# Read CSV file to Flask Restful API using cURL

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, flask

I am trying to develop as a service where someone can send the csv file to my REST API which I dump in the database. My `cURL` request is reading the data but `flask_restful` is not able to process it. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

**[EDITED BELOW]**

I found after reading the docs that `request.files` lets you read the files from the `POST` request from a form. I also found a way to send a csv file through `cURL` as a form.

```
class ForBetaAndUpload(Resource):
        def post(self, kind='quotes'):

#        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        file = request.files['file']
        print(file)
#        kind = parser.add_argument('kind').parse_args()['kind']

        if kind:
            if file and file[-3:]=='csv':
                if kind == 'quotes':
                    try:
                        df = pd.read_csv(file)
                        df.to_sql('QUOTES', helper.conx, index=False, if_exists='append')
                        return jsonify({'message':'%s rows inserted in the databasee table successfully' %(df.shape[0])})
                    except Exception as e:
                        return jsonify({'exception': e})

                if kind == 'trace':
                    try:
                        df = pd.read_csv(todos)
                        df.iloc[:10].to_sql('TRACE', helper.conx, index=False, if_exists='append')
                        return jsonify({'message':'%s rows inserted in the databasee table successfully' %(df.shape[0])})
                    except Exception as e:
                        return jsonify({'message': e})
            else:
                return jsonify({'message': 'Please provide a csv file'})
        else:
            return jsonify({'message':'Please provide the file for to update relevant table in the databse'})


    api.add_resource(ForBetaAndUpload, '/upload', endpoint='upload')

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

**cURL Request:**

```
curl "https://localhost:5000/upload" -X POST -H 'Content-Type: txt/csv' -d trace.csv --insecure
```

**I'm getting the following message:**

> curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown
>   protocol

**API Error Message**

> code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type
>   ('\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01ü\x03\x03\x08Ú:ü^¢Ù~ö7W\x9fDyy\x16j\x7fõ>½\x82\x90uÎ&3ÿZ\x08êE\x00\x00')

How can I send a csv file to the `flask` `restful_api`. Is it right what I am doing or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: try to use `curl -k` for bypass SSL cert

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan: I tried `curl -K "https://localhost:5000/upload" -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8' -d @trace.csv --insecure` and now I'm getting _Warning: error trying read config from the 'https://localhost:5000/upload' 
Warning: file
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information_

Comment: -k is lower case, why did you use httpS ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. So I changed it to `-k` and used `http` but now I'm `The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."`

Comment: found any solution here ?

Comment: @Wonay: Didn't find any solution to read csv through `flast_restful` however I solved it using `Flask` `POST` method. You can upload a csv file using `POSTMAN` and have `Flask` read it through `request.form`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @KrishnangKDalal I posted my solution below

Answer (score 1):

My solution to read csv from `Flask` is:

in Flask:

```
f = request.files['file']
```

`f` will be a handler to the file, you can then use `csv_reader`.

and to send the file:

```
curl -s "http://localhost:5000" \
    -F file=@./myfile.csv \
    -X POST \
    -H 'enctype:multipart/form-data ; Content-Type:multipart/form-data'
```

And that should works. Let me know.